# Check a String for several regex and say which one matched

Tags: java, regex

First of all I know there are already thousands of RegEx posts, sadly my google/stackoverflow search skills didn't help to find what I was looking for.

I have a Server client communication. The client awaits a user's input.
Then he sends it to the server and the server checks if it is a valid command.

```
Pattern lowercase = Pattern.compile("LOWERCASE.*");
Pattern  uppercase = Pattern.compile("UPPERCASE.*");
Pattern  reverse = Pattern.compile("REVERSE.*");
Pattern  bye = Pattern.compile("BYE");
Pattern  shutdown = Pattern.compile("SHUTDOWN");
```

If it starts with one of those commands, do a certain action.
I have problems creating a Matcher that checks for several patterns and then I want to go into something like

```
Matcher.matches(uppercase|reverse|bye|...) //Is this how I do it?
switch(inputString){
case(lowercase):  do something
case(reverse):    do something else
}
```

and so on.
I hope my request is understandable.
And there will be multiple clients talking to the server, in case this is relevant for the answer(like Threading and static Patterns dont work well or sth)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it pattern-by-pattern, and use an `if` instead of `switch`:

```
if (lowercase.matcher(inputStr).find()) {
    ... // Do something
} else if (reverse.matcher(inputStr).find()) {
    ... // Do something else
} else {
    ...
}
```

You can combine all patterns into one, and use *capturing groups* instead:

```
Pattern all = Pattern.compile(
    "(?<lower>LOWERCASE.*)|(?<upper>UPPERCASE.*)|(?<reverse>REVERSE.*)|..."
);
Matcher m = all.matcher(inputStr);
if (m.find()) {
    String upper = m.group("upper");
    String lower = m.group("lower");
    String reverse = m.group("reverse");
    if (upper != null) {
        ... // Do something
    }
    if (lower != null) {
        ... // Do something
    }
    if (reverse != null) {
        ... // Do something
    }
}
```

Note that the code above uses named capturing groups (`<upper>`, `<lower>`, etc.)

Comment: Ah yes, I feel like this is what I was looking for - using your second approach is faster? I thought I'd rather not use Pattern.matcher.(expression).find()   because it would be compiled again and again and again.. while the 2nd approach just compiles it once.
Is my understanding of this correct? I am still a beginner at programming.

Comment: @InDaPond It's not that bad, because each pattern would be compiled only once - namely, when you call `compile()`. However, multiple instances of `Matcher` would be created, which may be sub-optimal. Despite all that, you should pick the approach that reads better to you (and optionally to people who would be reviewing/maintaining your code). The speed is a distant second, because most of the time spent in your system would be passing the data to the server and back.

Comment: I tried to contact you via chat, but had no Idea how to. I have a follow-up question, maybe you want to visit me there, too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734233/mulserver-nooby-code-adress-already-in-use-but-it-is-not
Thanks!

Comment: I still have no valid response on this. Might take a look? @dasblinkenlight
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756825/threaded-server-stuck-on-accept-aka-how-to-shutdown-a-multhreaded-server-via-c

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is using a `Map` with the patterns mapping to objects like `Runnable` who are then called to execute the code. Alternativly you could map to strings and then have a `switch` statement for those stings to execute your code.

To check the patterns you would then simply iterate over the map and test each pattern with its own matcher.